# WPF : How to Get transformed rectangle coordinate?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there way to check the coordinates of a rectangle after doing a [`TranslateTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.translatetransform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?.

Let's say I have a rectangle

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle{ Width = 80, Height = 80};
```

and then I set the position of that rectangle

```
Canvas.setLeft(rect,512);
```

and then I animate it after adding it to Canvas.

```
var anim = new DoubleAnimation(0, 300, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)));
var trans = new TranslateTransform();
rect.RenderTransform = trans;
trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim);
```

How to get the new coordinates of the transformed rectangle?

I tried this

```
Canvas.GetLeft(rect[i].getRect);
```

and the result is still 512.

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**
I'm trying to delete the rectangle after it reaches some coordinate.

Comment: Obviously if you set Canvas.Left to 512 and then perform a TranslateTransform by 300 pixels in x direction, the final effective x position relative to the Canvas is 512+300=812 pixels. In order to keep things simple you should however not mix things, and only use either Canvas.Left or TranslateTransform.X. Both can be animated.

Comment: Thanks Clem. i just realized, Canvas itself can do animation. so what did i use is just rect.BeginAnimation(Canvas.XProperty,anim); and i can do Canvas.GetLeft(rect) from that animation :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe my problem is solved, but i always wonder if there is any other way. :)
so, i will really appreciate another answer.

here's what i've done.
Canvas.Left and TranslateTransform, both can have an animation. so for my simple question, im not mixing it anymore. i didnt use translate.
just do :

```
rect.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty,anim);
```

so with that, we can catch the coordinate of our rect while it is doing animation.
simply do :

```
Canvas.GetLeft(rect);
```

its the simplest way to do i think.

anyway, thanks to Clemens :)